# visual studio compiler errors on __IOS__ when building on windows

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am getting a compiler error I do not understand.  I have a dotnet core (.NET standard 2.0) project (originally created on mac). I am using visual studio on Windows 10 to edit/build it.  I get a compile error on code in a define.  I was expecting the code to be ignored during the build, like the editor displays.

Here's the class.

```
internal sealed class PoolAsync : IDisposable
    {
#if __IOS__
        [MonoPInvokeCallback(typeof(EventCompletedDelegate))]
#endif
    }
```

I've checked the configuration managers, project properties and I do not have **IOS** defined.  Not sure why I am getting these errors:

```
1>Pool\Async.cs(18,10,18,29): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MonoPInvokeCallbackAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
1>Pool\Async.cs(18,10,18,29): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MonoPInvokeCallback' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I do not get the errors when building from the command line:

any ideas?

Thnx
Matt

**edit**: if you wish to see the entire project, you can pull from my [github](https://github.com/tatmanblue/IndyDotNet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my problem.  The project (csproj) was set to target framework of netstandard2.0. I changed this to netcoreapp2.1 and all of those errors went away.

I had to manually edit the csproj file. The old target framework entry looked like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net452;xamarinios10</TargetFrameworks>
</PropertyGroup>
```

and updated to:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This does mean I no longer have xamarian support for iOS, however I am ok with that for the moment. The projects build on command line and in visual studio for both mac and windows.

Thnx
Matt